# FAILURE: Gradle Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have included the new Android library module (`dmxmediapicker`) project into my currently working library project (`Myapplication`), which I have used as a library for my Android module (`NormalProject`). But after including the Library module, gradle failed to build, and also it showed the `The input line is too long` exception.  How do I fix this?

**Exception**

```
:Myapplication:preDexDevDebug
:Myapplication:dexDevDebug
The input line is too long.

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Myapplication:dexDevDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\INO37\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\dex\dev\debug D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\classes\dev\debug D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes-787d89f55747f839e6edf29f29d38d35f17b3a30.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\support-annotations-20.0.0-240aab9bab6593b41d1b3b540c6045232da1fa77.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\cwac-sacklist-1.0.1-dda711d827778efe1c760bdb948ba1a39acfd793.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\converter-jackson-1.5.1-f30ef27d5fcffccb406fd4debc4dd598df411298.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\annotations-12.0-b5b365c95aae0dd9d05b7150051dc81ac4a66207.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes-6332debc38975f95cd72b9fb79d4ef959550aafc.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\android-viewbadger-6be9349f633a8c52e4e84a7473b884c75df7646f.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\cwac-merge-1.0.4-1690f7eaf3148874821653f2b44eb043d6dfac24.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes-9663eb2427df2a79f7656f8997524dff6aba8ed3.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\robospice-retrofit-1.4.12-7add9ad83809cfec85130664e3f0f8d8f4db3812.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\jackson-annotations-2.3.1-12e826dc80ebd316473afbc007d5d62fb9ca931f.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\apktool-lib-1.4.4-3-8ee8794680007892ea0aa71ccf4f62f403b090c0.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes-80d40aaa7e9898a9b07a24730ef98c587235ea59.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\slf4j-api-1.7.6-b9d683e8b480a08f5408a9b52ef0e5c371ce1989.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\eventbus-2.2.1-b9680385a60ef0d57864db42aa7b408c98a39042.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes-40c97f3059c5dbf257683f47006900cf32413fef.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\bolts-android-1.1.2-441bafc5a672d6d05e9a4e94445d14df854efa44.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\parent-app-template\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\robospice-cache-1.4.12-5cfde6eacf18940c1fb4721fafddd2699e39e6c8.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\parent-app-template\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\vixlet-core-536faacbfbdc9433aee1f435fdb78fcd538268f9.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\parent-app-template\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\library-2.6.0-6a4e906d7bcdb8616d57e8a005349bc659a4824e.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\robospice-1.4.12-003969d6ebfe39f32a146d77d99400c5484dc106.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\retrofit-1.5.1-10a09668d9b0d5fe5ca0227e21727fd008a69d4c.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\internal_impl-20.0.0-6592f598898c5eae47b6699221e16f83ae130dd0.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\library-2.4.0-99f385b1bc28f43ad47d88dcaaee564612041d59.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\commons-io-1.3.2-c3e895cac4d0af50751028ec6b5cf91e13a11944.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\logback-android-classic-1.1.1-2-e37f9f12967b461668ea7a08aa31566dc647e9cb.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\universal-image-loader-1.9.2-30f8c46db3505acf9c16140d5124dce613db573a.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\jackson-core-2.3.1-569c0b6fff725c0772a2544b76c505956a040cb3.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\logback-android-core-1.1.1-2-ba8bc87e327fe59477b1a30abe6b447e438a32c5.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\okhttp-1.5.4-41055e1ec4b4b9e132ba9b71d7cc04e5a8a5553d.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\twitter4j-core-4.0.2-84defff66a9193544b9ef0f2c15565686a93cf7b.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes-0cf819e9a2eb35706dd00dfff8f168e26bb6a9e5.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\commons-lang3-3.3.2-c4491073f0be9d854ecd8b34d316f7f2bc02ca21.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes-ce1a88d8493673e442b95c84f6ac34b0b16fd5e4.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes-499ae4fd3a32c9bb92892715a01ef3a35567e56c.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\classes-2b5d899cfe71f40eb1264e9826473d56e636ace6.jar D:\Jamal\Workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects\Workspace\From_GH_19_12_AND_63\Myapplication\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\dev\debug\jackson-databind-2.3.1-ad7662486febdd462bc1d048504a9658311ead09.jar
Error Code:
    255
Output:
    The input line is too long.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

**biuld.gradle for dmxmediapicker**

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
   
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
}
```

**biuld.gradle for MyApplication**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


android {
  
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 12
        
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

}

dependencies {  
 
    compile project(":dmxmediapicker") 
   
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
 
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
   
  }
```

**biuld.gradle for NormalProject**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



    android {
    
        compileSdkVersion 20
        buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }
        productFlavors {
           dev {
                   }
           staging {
            }
    
           production {
                 }
             }
    
    
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 12
            targetSdkVersion 20
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    
       
    
        buildTypes {
            debug {
              
                debuggable true
                signingConfig signingConfigs.test
            }
            release {
             
                debuggable false
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        compile project(':MyApplication')
    }
```

Comment: have you tried with buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

Comment: I think the directory names are quite large and windows doesnt support that long commands. Try to move your android project in D: drive not in any folder on D: . Might work!

Comment: @ ligi I have tried it now it is working fine.Post your answer here I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per `ligi's` comment

I have set the  `buildToolsVersion As 21.1.1` now the build issue have been solved.

Answer (score 0):

After installing `openjdk-11-jdk` my problem solved

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk`

NOTE: before installing jdk11 uninstall any other jdks

For example

`sudo apt autopurge openjdk-19-jdk:amd64 openjdk-19-jdk-headless:amd64 openjdk-19-jre:amd64 openjdk-19-jre-headless:amd64`

Answer (score -1):

**This will solve your problem**

In Android Studio, go to **Tools->SDK manager** and see that your **android version** is downloaded or not (for whatever emulator you have chosen as your virtual device).
If not download it and play the emulator again.

This should work now!!

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the files of my android folder was misconfigured as I did some changes before.
I Just created a new flutter app and copied the android folder from the new created app and pasted it to my previous flutter project  and that worked.

[image]

I know this is not an appropriate way to solve the problem but at least this solution could be useful in case you need to make it quick.