# ionic build android failed; 'failed to find Build Tools revision 22.0.1'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm getting this error when trying to build my ionic project for Android.
AILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:preBuild'.

> > failed to find Build Tools revision 22.0.1
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 3.315 secs

I already tried installing said Build Tools with `sudo android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-22.0.1`

it said it installed correctly, but it is still not working.
When I do `ionic platform remove android` and then `ionic platform add android` I can build the project, but this is not the solution

Is it possible that Android Studio does something with the gradle files? I'm not really familiar with Android programming, so I don't know what to look at

Comment: you have to set the build tool version

Comment: where? in ionic or android studio?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604936/failure-gradle-build-failed-with-an-exception look here

Comment: Thanks that worked! I've changed `buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion`to `buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"` in build .gradle, then Android Studio downloaded this Build Tool and it works now