# Gradle on adroid studio not working properly

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

Hello there I seriously need a help, I am a python programmer who just have started learning flutter, I have been sitting on one single error for 12 hours now.
I have tried every possible solution on the internet. I have re-installed android studio too, tried to fix xml files too. I am attaching the error below and a screenshot of my build.gradle too, please ask for more if need.

[image: Erro]

[image: andorid/build.gradle]

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604936/failure-gradle-build-failed-with-an-exception

Comment: Did it sir, same problem

Answer (score 0):

I also get this issue and in my case I found two solutions. First, rebuild the project or you can also try clean project. Second if your project is not big, you creat another fresh project and copy all codes from previous project to this new one and third but not in the list, go to settings and search gradle and then select the latest version of gradle or download it after finishing it restart the android studio with "run as administrator ". Hope it will works.